# How to scroll down the screen in the android espresso test? I need to validate the text present on the screen

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, android-espresso

I am performing the below test to validate the text on screen , The text is present on the view but need to page scroll to see the text manually.

```
 onView(withText("Launch")).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText("January 2010")).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Following error is coming, However the text is present on the view but need to page scroll to see the text manually.

> android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.
>   Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
>   Got: "TextView{id=2131361941, res-name=project_details_label_tv, visibility=VISIBLE, width=249, height=41, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=4.0, y=24.0, text=Status, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

Comment: I answered a question that will do just that here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218155/espresso-how-to-do-custom-swipe-e-g-swipetop-or-swipebottom/42399407#42399407 ...

Answer (score 25):

I don't know how this layout looks like, but to use

Just perform a `ViewActions.scrollTo()` before your assertion:

```
onView(withText("Launch"))
         .perform(ViewActions.scrollTo())
         .check(ViewAssertions‌​.matches(isDisplayed()));
```

you need to have `ScrollView` as your main view in structure.

If you have already LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, you have to change it to like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't believe your assertion about the ScrollView is correct.  The view has to be inside a scrollview, but that ScrollView does not need to be the parent (or main) view in the layout.

Comment: How to get it for compose UI testing?

Answer (score 23):

You can use SWIPE to scroll to the bottom of the screen:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(ViewActions.swipeUp());
```

For me its working nice.

Pablo

Comment: Thank you for sharing, it was something new for me. However, on API 33 ```swipeUp()``` leads to application goes into background in some interesting way. Checked Pixel3 emulator with API 33 installed on it.

Answer (score 9):

There is a solution to click in a button in a scroll view

```
onView(withId(R.id.onBottomOfScrollView)).perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

[Espresso: how to scroll to the bottom of ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387255/espresso-how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-scrollview)

Answer (score 6):

Just perform a `ViewActions.scrollTo()` before your assertion:

```
onView(withText("Launch")).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo()).check(ViewAssertions‌​.matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: * only "If the view you are working with is located inside a ScrollView".

Comment: This might throw "NoMatchingViewException".